# merge 2 collection into another with one same value in both laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hi i have 2 objects in laravel like below :

```
{
user_id: 34993,
price: "20000.00"
},
{
user_id: 35153,
price: "20000.00"
},
{
user_id: 35168,
price: "20000.00"
},
```

and the secound one is the user object :

```
[
{
id: 34993,
uuid: "8f8f2ba3-0d51-4fdb-83cd-6e13a0f2cc13",
fullname: "َUsersName",
email: null,
created_at: "2020-01-15 14:42:45",
updated_at: "2020-01-15 14:43:58",
email_verified_at: null,
gender: 2,
title: null
},
{
id: 35153,
uuid: "8f8f2ba3-0d51-4fdb-83cd-6e13a0f2cc13",
fullname: "َUsersName",
email: null,
created_at: "2020-01-15 14:42:45",
updated_at: "2020-01-15 14:43:58",
email_verified_at: null,
gender: 2,
title: null
},
{
id: 35168,
uuid: "8f8f2ba3-0d51-4fdb-83cd-6e13a0f2cc13",
fullname: "َUsersName",
email: null,
created_at: "2020-01-15 14:42:45",
updated_at: "2020-01-15 14:43:58",
email_verified_at: null,
gender: 2,
title: null
},
```

so now how can i add the price into the user object in second object or some how merge them with the key of user_id in first object and id of secound object because they are the same ?? my code is like below :

```
    {

        $data = DB::table('users_tracker')->where('user_id','>','34676')->where('action','LIKE','%gatewayResponse%')
            ->leftJoin('gateway_transactions',function($join){
                $join->on('gateway_transactions.ip','=','users_tracker.ip');
            })
            ->where('gateway_transactions.status','=','SUCCEED')
            ->select('user_id','price')
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
//        return $data;

       $user_id = $data->pluck('user_id');
        $users = User::whereIn('id',$user_id)->get();
        return $users;
    }
```

Comment: in `gateway_transactions` table

Comment: If the user_id column is unique on the first object, why not keep only one table and add the price field there as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use `User` to `join` the users_tracker like this:

```php
    User::join('users_tracker', 'users_tracker.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
              ->where('users_tracker.user_id','>','34676')
              ->where('users_tracker.action','LIKE','%gatewayResponse%')
              ->leftJoin('gateway_transactions',function($join){
                $join->on('gateway_transactions.ip','=','users_tracker.ip');
               })
              ->where('gateway_transactions.status','=','SUCCEED')
              ->select('*', 'users_tracker.user_id', 'gateway_transactions.price')
              ->groupBy('users_tracker.user_id', 'gateway_transactions.price')
              ->get();
```

It seems you have only_full_group_by problem.

Set the sql_mode in your config/database.php

```php
'mysql' => [
  ...
   'modes' => [
       'STRICT_ALL_TABLES',
       'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
       'NO_ZERO_DATE',
       'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
       'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
   ],
 ];
```

Remember to clear your config cache:

```sh
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json LINE 1: select distinct "users".*, "user_id", "price" from "users" i... ^ (SQL: select distinct "users".*, "user_id"

Comment: price is in gateway_transactions not user_tracker and when i change i get error

Comment: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: select "users".*, "users_tracker"."user_id", "gateway_transa... ^ (SQL:

Comment: I think you are using mysql 5.7+, so when u using group by, it will show `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` errors if the selected columns not all pass in group by

Comment: @Farshad you can use `selectRaw('ANY_VALUE(users.id), ANY_VALUE(col1), ...')`

Comment: how can that be done in my query i didnt get that unfortunately

Comment: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function any_value(integer) does not exist LINE 1: select ANY_VALUE(users.id), ANY_VALUE(users.id), ANY_VALUE(u... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select ANY_VALUE(users.id), ANY_VALUE(users.id),

Comment: @Farshad I don't know the real version of your mysql, it seems your mysql have no `any_value` function. So you can directly remove `only_full_group_by` in your sql_mode.

Comment: @Farshad try to reset the `mode` of your config/database like my post. And just use `->select('*', 'users_tracker.user_id', 'gateway_transactions.price')`